# Extracting number from txt using PHP

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$link = file_get_contents("file.txt");
if(preg_match_all('/\b[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{4}\b/', $link, $content, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)){

$content = array_unique($content[0]);
foreach($content as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $value;
    echo "<br>";
}

}
```

It always print out this number 1477276084 even that number isnt in the text file

the content of the textfile is

```
Name: 
Phone: 1477276084
Name: 
Phone: 2958692011
Name: 
Phone: 2958692011
Name: 
Phone: 2958692011
Name: 
Phone: 9954129334
Name: 
Phone: 123-812-4181
Name: 
Phone: 609-182-5123
Name: 
Phone: 609-182-5123
Name: 
Phone: 609-182-5123
Name: 
Phone: 609-182-5123
```

I even tried to change the file.txt into website and still the number is there

Comment: The number you say isn't in the file is the very first number in the file.

Comment: even you remove it try to remove it

Comment: Removed it and it's not there anymore... double check

Comment: If it prints that number, the number is in the file, where else could it come from?  Are you looking at a cached page?

Comment: I don't know but i tried it to chrome incognito a while back http://prnt.sc/d183u1
try to load any link, still the # is there

Comment: It's probably cached in your browser, or you're not updating the file that the server is using.

Comment: but i tried to put a link in the file_get_contents(); https://www.google.com and http://www.bing.com/ still the number is there but it changes the last numbers but still the number is there even the number isn't in the page/website